# Vue prop watch not working in class styled component

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component

I have one property called masterDatasourceId as following, which I am passing from parent component in ajax call.

But watch method is not being called. Following is my code.

```
  @Prop()
  masterDatasourceId!: number;

  @Watch('masterDatasourceId')
  masterDatasourceIdChanged(newVal: number) {
    // Even though masterDatasourceId changes, it is not coming up here.
  }
```

What am I missing in here? I am using class styled typescript based vue component.

I wanted to get it using following getter setter method.

```
  private _masterDatasourceId!: number;
  public get masterDatasourceId(): number {
    return this._masterDatasourceId;
  }

  @Prop()
  public set masterDatasourceId(value: number) {
    console.log('this I wanted to use as a watcher if possible...!!!')
    this._masterDatasourceId=value;
  }
```

But it was giving following run time error.

```
The computed property "masterDatasourceId" is already defined as a prop.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems immediate true is required for this. Working after this change

```
@Watch('masterDatasourceId', { immediate: true })
  masterDatasourceIdChanged(newVal: number) {
}
```